# Can't able to run jmeter in non GUI mode

Tags: jmeter

I am able to open and work on Jmeter in GUI.But when i try to open in non gui mode I get the following error,

Creating summariser 
Created the tree successfully using D:\testlan.jmx
Starting standalone test @ 2023 May 8 18:13:27 IST (1683549807865)
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445
Uncaught Exception java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError in thread Thread[StandardJMeterEngine,5,main]. See log file for details.

Jmeter command : jmeter -Jenvironment="perf" -n -t D:\testplan.jmx -f -l results.jtl -e -o report

Java : 17
Jmeter : 5.5

Answer (score 2):

The error messages says `See log file for details.` so this is something you should do. If you're not able to figure out the root cause of the problem by looking into the log file you can:

- [increase JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) to DEBUG level
- update your question with WARN, ERROR and FATAL lines of the log file (or better provide the full log)

Most common problems which prevent JMeter test from being executed are:

- The test plan uses a [JMeter Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) which is not installed
- You're suffering from a form of a [Jar Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell)
- There is an obvious error in your test plan and/or JMeter configuration

Comment: Sorry for not providing enough details.Kindly find the detailed exception below

Comment: Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Conflicting module versions. Module [groovy-datetime is loaded in version 3.0.11 and you are trying to load version 4.0.0-beta-1
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl$DefaultModuleListener.onModule(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:510) ~[groovy-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
 at

Comment: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanExtensionModuleFromProperties(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:87) ~[groovy-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanExtensionModuleFromMetaInf(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:81) ~[groovy-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanClasspathModulesFrom(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:63) ~[groovy-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]

Comment: at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanClasspathModules(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:54) ~[groovy-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:125) ~[groovy-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:86) ~[groovy-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
 at groovy.lang.GroovySystem.<clinit>(GroovySystem.java:37) ~[groovy-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]

Comment: As I assumed a Jar Hell, [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5) comes with [Groovy 3.0.11](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/gradle.properties#L92) and you added Groovy 4.0.0-beta-1 for some reason. Remove it and your test should start working (or at least this error will go away)

Comment: I have checked in JMETER_HOME /bin directory for another groovy versions but I have found only 3.0.11 version only.But I have installed Groovy4.0.11 in my machine.Will there be a conflict because of this?

Comment: Check all folders which are in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath). If you're still not able to figure out where the .jar is coming from - use [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter) and inspect [`java.class.path` system property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html), it lists all .jars with their absolute paths used by JMeter.

Comment: Apparently the mismatched groovy version was referring from the jar file in my classpath and issue is fixed after building jar with proper version.Thanks Dmitri.I was able to solve this issue.